# Can't play any videos on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

I get "An error occurred. Try again later" whenever I play a video on Google Drive, uploaded by myself or anyone else. How do I fix this problem?

I found that videos which I add to Google Drive are playable when they're freshly uploaded but become unplayable when they get old. Does Google Drive delete files for "inactivity"? I hope not!

Comment: The question hasn't enough details. It's worth to note that the model of [se] doesn't work well for questions that require a lot of back and forth.

Comment: it could be connectivity issues. check your net strength.